# Creating array from query results and pushing multiple values to associated key

Tags: php

I have an object of query results. Each result has two columns: abbreviation and text. I need to create a new array, where I want to store values from 'text' column grouped by values in 'abbreviation' column.

I tried this:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
  $results_by_book_abbreviation[$result->abbreviation] = $result->text;
}
```

What I get is an array with multiple keys, but each key has only one value, but my object has multiple values with the same key.

It worked in PHP 5.5.38, now I have PHP 7.0.13

Comment: This code should not have been affected from the change to 7.0.13. I would guess your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Array KEYS are UNIQUE, so if you load a key more than once you are overwriting the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array KEYS are UNIQUE, so if you load a key more than once you are overwriting it's contents each time.

So create an array below `$results_by_book_abbreviation[$result->abbreviation]` like this

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $results_by_book_abbreviation[$result->abbreviation][] = $result->text;
        //                            the change        ^^
}
```

> This would have been wrong in any version of PHP so it is not related to you changing the version of PHP that is running this code

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an array of array as follows:

```
foreach ($results as $result) 
{
   if(!isset($results_by_book_abbreviation[$result->abbreviation]))
   {
        $results_by_book_abbreviation[$result->abbreviation] = array();
   }
   $results_by_book_abbreviation[$result->abbreviation][] = $result->text;
}
```

Comment: That `if` is basically unnecessary